# UITextField not displaying text after viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to fill in the form, on load of a view. I am doing this by setting the properties in `viewDidLoad()`.

I have a couple of fields that are working as expected, e.g. `UIButton` or `UILabel` elements. However, I also have a custom-build class `AITextField: UITextField` that doesn't display the text I'm setting with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    textField.text = name 
}
```

From what I can see the property is still present at the end of `viewWillAppear()` but is set to empty at the beginning of `viewDidAppear()`.

I don't see any code in `AITextField` class that would reset the 'text' value to empty at any point.

Any hints on where to look would be appreciated. Both functions are really simple:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print(textField.text)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)        
    print(textField.text)
}
```

Comment: It's better if you add some code related to `AITextField` and your `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: I added the two functions, they are really simple though. I can't exactly post the whole AITextField class because it's huge. What could be relevant?

Comment: Try this **print(textField.text!)** If this not works then do this simply add some text to that `textField` from `storyBoard` and then try to print value in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: Try overriding text property in AITextField and add property observer didSet or willSet. You can add a breakpoint or print statement there and the you could debug why the text property is getting set as empty

Comment: Where/When do you set the text fields text?

Comment: Show the context where you are setting `textField.text = name`. And also the bounding classes too.

Comment: I am setting this property at the end of viewDidLoad:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.text = name
}

Comment: Double check your `name` value. Try to print `name` value wether it is `nil` or not.

Comment: If there was something wrong with the name value it wouldn't be set properly in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Is the text field that you are setting the value to, the same text field being displayed?

Comment: Yes. You can see that I'm printing the values from the same field, in viewWillAppear it's present, in viewDidAppear it's empty.

Comment: @MartaPanuszewska _"You can see that I'm printing the values from the same field, in viewWillAppear it's present, in viewDidAppear it's empty"_ How are we supposed to verify this? We can only come to random assumptions which may have nothing to do with your problem with the information you have provided.

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to wrap:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        textField.text = name 
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` is called on the main queue though. You may have some other casualties that is causing the behavior.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21047578)

Comment: If this is your solution, then your question was clearly incomplete: please add the missing pieces of reproducibility in your question, or delete it altogether.

Comment: @William Isted, Well, this has been posted by the author as the solution to his problem... I don't think OP is going to ask clarification to herself